# Running 2 WLS instance on a same server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a WLS 12.1.3 running on an instance.

I was working to spin up WLS 12.2.1.3 on the same machine on a different port.

After the 12.2 installation i confirmed that ./startWeblogic.sh and ./startNodeManager runs fine.

but when I try to start the ManagedServer in WLS console, i get an error

**For server ManagedServer, the Node Manager associated with machine Machine-1 is not reachable.
Message icon - Warning All of the servers selected are currently in a state which is incompatible with this operation or are not associated with a running Node Manager or you are not authorized to perform the action requested. No action will be performed.

In WLS console, under environment>machine>machine_1>monitoring I see an error even tho Keystore/SSL tab is configured correctly (configured same as 12.1.3 which has no problem starting managed server)

**Status: | Inactive | Current status of this Node Manager.More Info...
Problem description: | javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException | Exception encountered while communicating with this node manager.More Info...
Version: | (not available)

To add a little more context, nodemanager.properties is pointing to port 5557 same as nodemanager in WLS console.

when i upgraded one of our training environment from 12.1.3. to 12.2.1.3, it had no issue.

Any feedback will be appreciated and please let me know if more information is needed.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure a `machine` in the new domain?

```
<machine>
  <name>MACHINENAME</name>
  <node-manager>
    <name>MACHINENAME</name>
    <nm-type>Plain</nm-type>
    <listen-address>localhost</listen-address>
    <listen-port>5557</listen-port>
    <debug-enabled>false</debug-enabled>
  </node-manager>
</machine>
```

Make sure that you also update the `<listen-port>` for the machine to 5557 or it won't communicate to the correct Node Manager (linked to the new server). Also remember to update the `<nm-type>` property to `Plain` if you are not using `SSL`. Try it in this mode first to rule out an `SSL` configuration error.

All of this can be configured via the Configuration Wizard in 12.2.1.x but if you accidentally miss one of these, a real pain to track down.